# Python Pandas - Iterating inside Groupby to find time differences

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, group-by

I have a **Pandas dataframe** which look [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dWWI1.png)

The customer number is unique to each customer, but repeats itself if the customer visits again.
I want to groupby customer number. Then in each groupby object, I want to find out the duration between visits.

So, I do it like this..

```
df['Date'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d %b %y')
grouped = df.groupby('Customer no')
```

My question is,
how do I iterate over the grouped rows and find out the time (in days) between subsequent visits.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with [`diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html):

```
print (df.groupby('Customer no')['Date'].diff())
13      NaT
22   0 days
26   0 days
Name: Date, dtype: timedelta64[ns]

#if need convert days to numeric
print (df.groupby('Customer no')['Date'].diff() / np.timedelta64(1, 'D'))
13    NaN
22    0.0
26    0.0
Name: Date, dtype: float64
```

[Frequency conversion](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timedeltas.html#frequency-conversion).